# Shapes drawn on an image is inverted when written into PDF file part 2

Tags: java, swing, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF file that I converted into an image. I Was able to write on top of the image but when I tried to save the shapes/lines into the pdf, the point are not their place and the shapes are inverted.

This is related to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387803/shapes-drawn-on-an-image-is-inverted-when-written-into-pdf-file) question and it the first part was already answered. Now the second problem was when I try to scale the image. the points are not in their places.

I found out that it is not working when the scale is changed.. I updated the code and added the `Translate` values to the `moveTo` and `lineTo` as a parameter and it somehow worked when the scale is on default which is `72/200f`.

Thank you Tilman Hausherr for your patience..

**NOTE :** Hold CTRL then use mouse wheel to zoom in/out. This event can change the scale and thus messing up with the points of my shape.

```
package pdfwriter;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;

public class SO57387803DrawShapesInPDF {

    private static class MyImagePanel extends JPanel {

        final BufferedImage image;
        //final float scale = .38f;
        final int DPI = 200;
        float scale = 72f / DPI;

        //NEW
        double affineX;
        double affineY;

        AffineTransform atg;
        Point start = new Point();
        Point end = new Point();
        boolean isNewLine = true;
        static ArrayList<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        static PDDocument document;

        public MyImagePanel() throws IOException {
            document = PDDocument.load(new File("c:\\users\\john ebarita\\documents\\plan.pdf"));
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

            image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, DPI, ImageType.RGB);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (end != start) {
                        Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);

                        lines.add(line);
                        Point2D p = calcCoordinates(e);

                        start = new Point();
                        start.x = (int) p.getX();
                        start.y = (int) p.getY();

                        repaint();
                    }

                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point2D p = calcCoordinates(e);
                    end = new Point();

                    end.x = (int) p.getX();
                    end.y = (int) p.getY();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

                    int rotation = e.getWheelRotation();

                    //Zoom in/out on CTRL
                    if (e.isControlDown()) {

                        if (rotation < 0) {
                            scale -= .05;
                        } else {
                            scale += .05;
                        }
                        if (scale < .2) {
//                            IMAGE_SCALE = (float) .2;
                        } else if (scale > 4) {
                            scale = 4;
                        }
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private Point2D calcCoordinates(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            try {
                return atg.inverseTransform(p, null);
            } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
                return p;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();

//          double  affineX = (getWidth() - scale * image.getWidth()) / 2;
//          double affineY = (getHeight() - scale * image.getHeight()) / 2;
//          updated
            affineX = (getWidth() - scale * image.getWidth()) / 2;
            affineY = (getHeight() - scale * image.getHeight()) / 2;

            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.translate(affineX, affineY);
            at.scale(scale, scale);

            AffineTransform atf = g2D.getTransform();
            atf.concatenate(at);
            atg = (AffineTransform) at.clone();

            g2D.setTransform(atf);

            g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            try {
                g2D.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }

            for (Line2D l : lines) {
                g2D.draw(l);
            }

            g2D.dispose();
        }

        public void save() {

            try {
                PDPage page = document.getPage(0);

                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true);
                contentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, page.getMediaBox().getHeight()));
                for (Line2D l : lines) {
                    Point2D p1 = new Point2D.Double(l.getX1(), l.getY1());
                    Point2D p2 = new Point2D.Double(l.getX2(), l.getY2());

                    p1 = atg.transform(p1, null);
                    p2 = atg.transform(p2, null);

//                    contentStream.moveTo((float) (p1.getX()), page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (float) (p1.getY() ));
//                    contentStream.lineTo((float) (p2.getX()), page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (float) (p2.getY() ));
                    //UPATED
                    contentStream.moveTo((float) (p1.getX() - affineX), page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (float) (p1.getY() - affineY));
                    contentStream.lineTo((float) (p2.getX() - affineX), page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (float) (p2.getY() - affineY));

                    contentStream.stroke();
                }

                contentStream.close();

                document.save(new File("c:\\users\\john ebarita\\documents\\saved.pdf"));
                document.close();
                System.out.println("file saved");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
//                Logger.getLogger(SO57387803DrawShapesInPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int width = (int) (scale * image.getWidth());
            int height = (int) (scale * image.getHeight());
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF");
        frame.setSize(1500, 1200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // MyImagePanel imagePanel = null;
        MyImagePanel imagePanel;
        try {
            imagePanel = new MyImagePanel();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
//            Logger.getLogger(SO57387803DrawShapesInPDF.class
//                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return; // or there would be an uninitialized variable
        }

        JButton btn = new JButton("Save");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                imagePanel.save();
                //MyImagePanel.save();
            }
        });

        btn.setBounds(10, 0, 70, 30);

        frame.add(btn);
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.add(imagePanel);
        pnl.setBounds(0, 100, 1500, 1200);
        frame.add(pnl);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference regardless of the dpi, maybe it depends on the PDF file and that is why I've often told to share a link to your file (or to a public file that has the same effect). I also see that you are doing a rotation, this will of course only work nicely with a rotated file.

Comment: Sir have you tried this code?..
I added a `mouseWheelListener` that zoom in/out of the image.
Therefore the scale is changed and messes up with the points.
And the page that I am using is in 270 rotation.

Comment: moving the mouse wheel has no visible effect for me, nor does your text mention that one should use it and what to expect.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add mention it in my question. You need to hold the CTRL key before moving the mouse wheel for it to zoom.

Comment: OK, got it. If you change the scale, then you need to change DPI as well. Or you render the PDF page with `renderImage`, but I suspect that the scale parameter needs to be `1f / scale`.

Comment: What really is the significance of `72/200f` or `72/DPI` ? for what I  know , it is only used to give a scale that is used to make the image appear relative to the `container` size which is `MyImagePanel`.

Comment: I don`t understand why I need to change the DPI every time I change the scale or I am not getting what you mean? Also I cannot afford to use `renderImage` because I need the `AffineTransform` set on the `graphics` itself. Thank you.

Comment: And one more thing , I know its off the topic but is it possible to extract line segments on a pdf using pdfbox? Like table borders  and lines from pdf and I want to have there coordinates.

Comment: The image is displayed in a specific resolution (you start with 200 dots per inch), so when you click on such an image the position is the position of a bigger image than 1:1 which is 72 dpi per PDF standard (1 PDF page unit = 1/72 inch), thus the need to adjust. Re extracting the line segments see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931422/pdfbox-2-0-2-calling-of-pagedrawer-processpage-method-caught-exceptions

Comment: If you can't use "renderImage", then recalculate the dpi if you change the scale - it makes no sense to "zoom" on the same image, it will be bigger but without more details.

Comment: And btw I tried with a 270 rotated image - it is not "inverted". It is just the scale that doesn't match.

Comment: Yes the image is not inverted but the scale is doesn't match. And now I am using `drawRenderedImage()`. Any Idea on how the match the scale? I also want to try to change the DPI but I don't where to start. Do I have to call `renderer.renderImageWithDPI();` again?

Comment: Finally got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of trial and error I think I got the answer to my problem with the scale and points.

I started off with `72/200f` scale.So what I did was I made that the did was after transforming the points I divide with the `currentScale/firstScale`, then divide it to the transformed points;

**Thank you Tilman Hausherr** for the helping me.

```
  p1 = atg.transform(p1, null);
  p2 = atg.transform(p2, null);

 contentStream.moveTo((float) (p1.getX() / (scale / .36)), (float) page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - p1.getY() / (scale / .36)));
 contentStream.lineTo((float) (p2.getX() / (scale / .36)), (float) (page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - p2.getY() / (scale / .36)));
```

Full Code;

```
package pdfwriter;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;

public class SO57387803DrawShapesInPDF {

    private static class MyImagePanel extends JPanel {

        final BufferedImage image;
        //final float scale = .38f;
        final int DPI = 200;
        float scale = 72f / DPI;

        //NEW
        double affineX;
        double affineY;

        AffineTransform atg;
        Point start = new Point();
        Point end = new Point();
        boolean isNewLine = true;
        static ArrayList<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        static PDDocument document;

        public MyImagePanel() throws IOException {
            document = PDDocument.load(new File("plan.pdf"));
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

            image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, DPI, ImageType.RGB);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (end != start) {
                        Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);

                        lines.add(line);
                        Point2D p = calcCoordinates(e);

                        start = new Point();
                        start.x = (int) p.getX();
                        start.y = (int) p.getY();

                        repaint();
                    }

                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point2D p = calcCoordinates(e);
                    end = new Point();

                    end.x = (int) p.getX();
                    end.y = (int) p.getY();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

                    int rotation = e.getWheelRotation();

                    //Zoom in/out on CTRL
                    if (e.isControlDown()) {

                        if (rotation < 0) {
                            scale -= .05;
                        } else {
                            scale += .05;
                        }
                        if (scale < .2) {
                            scale = .2f;
                        } else if (scale > 4) {
                            scale = 4;
                        }
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private Point2D calcCoordinates(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            try {
                return atg.inverseTransform(p, null);
            } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
                return p;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            //          double  affineX = (getWidth() - scale * image.getWidth()) / 2;
            //          double affineY = (getHeight() - scale * image.getHeight()) / 2;
            //          updated
            affineX = (getWidth() - scale * image.getWidth()) / 2;
            affineY = (getHeight() - scale * image.getHeight()) / 2;

            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.translate(affineX, affineY);
            at.scale(scale, scale);

            AffineTransform atf = g2D.getTransform();
            atf.concatenate(at);
            atg = (AffineTransform) at.clone();

            g2D.setTransform(atf);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            try {
                g2D.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }

            for (Line2D l : lines) {
                g2D.draw(l);
            }

            g2D.dispose();
        }

        public void save() {

            try {
                PDPage page = document.getPage(0);

                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true);
                contentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, page.getMediaBox().getHeight()));
                for (Line2D l : lines) {
                    Point2D p1 = new Point((int) l.getX1(), (int) l.getY1());
                    Point2D p2 = new Point((int) l.getX2(), (int) l.getY2());

                    p1 = atg.transform(p1, null);
                    p2 = atg.transform(p2, null);

                    //UPATED
                    System.out.println("Points");
                    System.out.println(p1);
                    System.out.println(p2);
                    System.out.println("Scale " + scale);

                    //0.36 is the default scale or 72/200f 
                    contentStream.moveTo((float) (p1.getX() / (scale / .36)), (float) (page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - p1.getY() / (scale / .36)));

                    contentStream.lineTo((float) (p2.getX() / (scale / .36)), (float) (page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - p2.getY() / (scale / .36)));

                    contentStream.stroke();
                }

                contentStream.close();

                document.save(new File("c:\\users\\john ebarita\\documents\\saved.pdf"));
                document.close();
                System.out.println("file saved");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //                Logger.getLogger(SO57387803DrawShapesInPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int width = (int) (scale * image.getWidth());
            int height = (int) (scale * image.getHeight());
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF");
        frame.setSize(1500, 1200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // MyImagePanel imagePanel = null;
        MyImagePanel imagePanel;
        try {
            imagePanel = new MyImagePanel();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //            Logger.getLogger(SO57387803DrawShapesInPDF.class
            //                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return; // or there would be an uninitialized variable
        }

        JButton btn = new JButton("Save");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                imagePanel.save();
                //MyImagePanel.save();
            }
        });

        btn.setBounds(10, 0, 70, 30);

        frame.add(btn);
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.add(imagePanel);
        pnl.setBounds(0, 100, 1500, 1200);
        frame.add(pnl);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```